# Syntax error in pandas dataframe slice in my sklearn data prep?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, pandas

I'm new to sklearn and having trouble formatting the data to predict and evaluate a confusion matrix.  I'm using this [Random Forest tutorial](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/random-forests-in-python.html).

Here is my code

```
 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 dataframe = pd.read_csv('output.txt', sep='\t')
 df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
 df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75

 train, test = df[df['is_train']==True], df[df['is_train']==False]
 features = df.columns[1:5]
 clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)
 y, _ = pd.factorize(train['event_count'])
 clf.fit(train[features], y)
```

It's this line for my predictions which is giving me the error:

```
 preds = df[:6][clf.predict(test[features])]
 IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write numpy style slices in dataframe, like :

```
observations = data[:6]
```

Try DataFrame.ix

```
df.ix[:,6:]
```

Cf panda indexing : [Panda indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-advanced)

Comment: my issue was my 'test' variable did not get exectuted the first time around. so now that works.